# Bulk Insert From DataTable to Access Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Already have the DataTable populated but need to dump its entire table contents into an Access database.

```
Using (conn)
    If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then conn.Open()
    Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " & sMdbTableName, conn)
    adapter.InsertCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO " & sMdbTableName & " SELECT * FROM " & sMdbTableNameSource & ";", conn)
    adapter.TableMappings.Add(sMdbTableName, ds.Tables.Item(sMdbTableNameSource).ToString)
    adapter.Update(ds.Tables.Item(sMdbTableNameSource))
End Using
```

Im trying to do something like this but no errors and no data added. Need the best performing way.

Thanks

Edit:

Updated code is slow as heck and need a bulk type of access import:

```
        Using (conn)
            If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then conn.Open()
            Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
            adapter.InsertCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO " & sMdbTableName & "(Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5) VALUES(@Field1, @Field2, @Field3, @Field4, @Field5);", conn)
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Field1", OleDbType.VarChar, 16, "Field1")
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Field2", OleDbType.VarChar, 16, "Field2")
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Field3", OleDbType.VarChar, 16, "Field3")
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Field4", OleDbType.VarChar, 16, "Field4")
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Field5", OleDbType.VarChar, 16, "Field5")
            adapter.TableMappings.Add(sMdbTableName, ds.Tables.Item(sMdbTableNameSource).ToString)
            adapter.Update(ds.Tables.Item(sMdbTableNameSource))
        End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `RowState` of every `DataRow` in your `DataTable` will be `Unchanged` and therefore they will be ignored when you call `Update`.  If you want to insert those rows then their `RowState` must be `Added`.  You can make that happen by setting the `AcceptChangesDuringFill` property of the data adapter to `False` before calling `Fill`.  That will prevent `AcceptChanges` being called after the `DataTable` is populated, which is what changes the `RowState` properties from `Added` to `Unchanged`.  If that's not an option then you must loop through the rows and call `SetAdded` on each one.

Comment: Thank You for your quick response.

I made the change to the da and retested it but still same issue.
I'm mentally burnt today but I think my sql statement may not be accurate now. The DataTable is "[CodeSource]" and the table to be created in the db is "[Code]". Reflective in hte variable names too.

Answer (score 1):

DataTables essentially use all row-by-row processing.

So if you need to do a push from your .net code into Access, looping through the table rows and running a simple Update statement using the values from the row - in a separate command - is not the worst thing.

The Insert/Update "statements" in the DataTable will result in the same behavior.  So if you're tired and can't get them to work, you can bail out to a separate Update :).

If you were going to SQLServer, the SQLBulkCopy object would be perfect and should be faster.  Unfortunately, I'm not aware of an object like that for Access.
That would be what to search for.

Comment: Fresh morning and fresh mind helps wonders lol. I found the spot where I missed setting AcceptChangesDuringFill and changed my insert to a parameterized insert but its freakin slow. I have about 1,000,000 records to import and cant really use SQL server although we do have it.

Comment: oh, wow.  1mil is a lot for Access....  I always think tens of thousands is when people get into trouble and get ready to upgrade.

Comment: You know you can use the free SQL Express in production now, officially, right?  It has less features and such, but could already be much better than Access.

Comment: Due to the project constraints and how the clients are running the program we cannot use SQL Server and we do have it too.

Also, looking into replacing Access with SQLCE

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub CopyDatatableToAccess(dt As DataTable, AccsessAddress As String, TableName As String)
    Try
        Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & AccsessAddress & ";Persist Security Info=False;"
        Dim accConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString)
        Dim selectCommand As String = "SELECT <field1>, <field2> and so on FROM <table>" & TableName
        Dim accDataAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, accConnection)
        Dim accCommandBuilder As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder()
        accDataAdapter.InsertCommand = accCommandBuilder.GetInsertCommand()
        accDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = accCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
        Dim accDataTable As DataTable = dt.Copy()
        ''Just to make sure, set the RowState to added to make sure an Insert is performed'
        For Each row As DataRow In accDataTable.Rows '
            If row.RowState = DataRowState.Added Or DataRowState.Unchanged Then '
                row.SetAdded() '
            End If '
        Next '
        accDataAdapter.Update(accDataTable)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this forum. Please edit your answer to include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves OP's problem.