# Problems updating a database using vb.net, oledbdataadapter

Tags: vb.net, oledbconnection, oledbcommand, oledbdataadapter

After going over multiple questions/answers on Stackoverflow and other boards I'm still lost on why I can't update an Access database from a datatable. I'm trying to take data from a datatable and insert that data into an Access table if it is blank, and replace the table if it already has data. I can successfully replace the table, but the data from the datatable does not get added.

However, the method which I'm using does not appear to work. My datatable comes from a bound datagridsource and the Access layer is called like this:

`ConnectedDB.UpdateTable(DBTable, bsDataSource.DataSource)`

Where `ConnectedDB` is the Access Layer class, `DBTable` is the string containing the Access table name, and `bsDataSource` is the bound data. As you can see, I passed the `.Datasource` to turn it into a datatable.

Here is the original (pre-Jan 29th) section of my work to add the datatable back into the Access table:

```
 Public Function UpdateTable(strTable As String, dgDataTable As DataTable) As Boolean
        Dim DS As New DataSet
        dgDataTable.TableName = strTable
        DS.Tables.Add(dgDataTable)
        Using OpenCon = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)
            Using DataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " & strTable, OpenCon)
                Dim DBcmd As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(DataAdapter)
                DBcmd.QuotePrefix = "["
                DBcmd.QuoteSuffix = "]"
                DataAdapter.UpdateCommand = DBcmd.GetUpdateCommand()
                Try
                    OpenCon.Open()
                    DataAdapter.Fill(DS.Tables(strTable))
                    If DataAdapter.Update(DS.Tables(strTable)) > 0 Then
                        Return True
                    Else Return False
                    End If
                Catch exo As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(exo.Message)
                    Return False
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
```

My function tries to update an existing Access table with the name represented as `strTable` with the information in the datatable, `dgDataTable` from a datagridview. Each run hits the update check > 0 and returns a false which means syntax wise it should be working (i.e. no error messages). I have traced the table and it has all the data it should have (so the information is getting passed correctly from the grid through the update commands). I was playing with applying it in a dataset but I'm not sure I really need that.

I was tracing the variables through the update method and I think I found out why it won't update but I'm not sure what to do about it. The query it comes up with is like this:

```
UPDATE [RtoC] SET [R] = ?, [C] = ?, [Type] = ?, [Unknown] = ? WHERE (([R] = ?) AND ([C] = ?) AND ([Type] = ?) AND ((? = 1 AND [Unknown] IS NULL) OR ([Unknown] = ?)))
```

The Access table name is RtoC with fields R, C, Type, and unknown.
I'm thinking the "?" are not getting filled in causing the query to just not apply data back to Access. I'm not sure though how to set those items.

EDIT 1/29/20: I used the code changes I and jmcihinney document below and it does insert the lines into the Access table. This edit alters the question to be more specific about what I'm am trying to do, and how the datatable is created. Hopefully this clears up some wording on my part and provides some basis for the alteration of the row state.

Comment: It looks (to me) like this line: `DataAdapter.Fill(DS.Tables(strTable))` will wipe the contents of your table, and on the next line, you just try to use an unchanged data table for an update.  Put a break-point before & after you do `DataAdapter.Fill()` and see if your tablecount or rowcount confirms what I'm saying.

Comment: To clarify: when I said "wipe the contents", I meant that you over-wrote the DataTable that you passed-into this function and added to the DataSet on line 2.

Comment: I had the exact same idea so I traced that through to the update and beyond. It retains the data that I initially put into it which may mean that something might not be firing off correctly which is why I then began tracing the adapter query to see why.

Comment: Can a connection string allow the connection to open the file but stop queries from interacting with the database? One of the changes I made was to move from Jet to ACE (4.0 to 12.0).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `Fill` method of that data adapter calls `AcceptChanges` on the `DataTable` after populating it, thus there are no changes to save when you call `Update`.

That call to `Fill` shouldn't be there anyway though, because you don't want to retrieve any data, just save changes.  You've got a whole lot of pointless code there.  It should look more like this:

```
Public Function UpdateTable(strTable As String, dgDataTable As DataTable) As Boolean
    Using DataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " & strTable, strConnectionString)
        Dim DBcmd As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(DataAdapter)

        DBcmd.QuotePrefix = "["
        DBcmd.QuoteSuffix = "]"

        Try
            Return DataAdapter.Update(dgDataTable) > 0
        Catch exo As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(exo.Message)
            Return False
        End Try
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I agree there were some odds and ends I should remove as I was trying different approaches to datasets/tables. What is interesting is that the datatable never actually changes even when it is the subject of the ```fill```. You'd think it would at least alter itself with information from the database based on my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I took another tack at manipulating the database and in looking that up, I found the answer provided by jmcilhinney back in 2014! [[Bulk Insert From DataTable to Access Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152126/bulk-insert-from-datatable-to-access-database])

In a `for each` loop across the rows of my datatable I set this:
`row.SetAdded()`

If I was filling I would have done something like:
`DataAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = True` 
Before the `Fill` command.

Unless this method has changed or there is a better way, I'll mark the link as the answer.

Thanks jmcilhinney....twice!

Comment: This brings up a number of questions. It now seems like you wanted to insert records, while your original question indicated that you wanted to update. Which is it? Secondly, if you are adding records to a `DataTable` then their `RowState` should be `Added` by default, so you must be doing something to change that. The most obvious reason is that you're calling `AcceptChanges` somewhere. I'd be interested to know more details about the life-cycle of this data. If you're interested in getting to the root of the problem, rather than using a workaround, you can update your question.

Comment: You are correct in that I have perhaps used the wrong word in "Update". Essentially I'm inserting a datatable into a blank Access table, or, in the case of having data, updating the values to their new set. I'll also alter the question a little to show the caller for the datatable.